# input type number is returning null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On sumbit of the form  to a ng-controller, I am getting null for the field named capital , in the controller defined below

```
<input id="capital" name="capital" pattern="(^\d+(\.|\,)\d{2})" type="number" min="0.00" step="0.01"     placeholder=""  required="" ng-model="capital">
```

However I am able to get correct data on my controller when I input decimal value in it

here is my controller

```
$scope.addCustomer=function(){
var data_to_send={};
    data_to_send.capital=$scope.capital;
    alert(data_to_send.capital);
}
```

**In other words**

when i try to alert the field capital in my ng-controller

10.10 alert prints 10.10 but for 10 it prints undefined

Comment: fiddle please. not able to simulate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change `pattern` to this

```
<input id="capital" name="capital" pattern="(^\d+(\.|\,\d{2})?)" type="number" min="0.00" step="0.01" placeholder="" required="" ng-model="capital">
```

Comment: that worked , thanks. please share the reason aswell

Comment: @Count your regex does not match numbers like this `10`, I've changed regex to match numbers like these `10`, `10.10`, `10,10`.